# Are there guidelines for updating C++Builder applications for C++Builder 2009?

Tags: unicode, c++builder, vcl

I have a range of Win32 VCL applications developed with C++Builder from BCB5 onwards, and want to port them to ECB2009 or whatever it's now called.

Some of my applications use the old TNT/TMS unicode components, so I have a good mix of AnsiStrings and WideStrings throughout the code. The new version introduces UnicodeString, and a bunch of #defines that change the way functions like c_str behave.

I want to modify my code in a way that is as backwards-compatible as possible, so that the same code base can still be compiled and run (in a non-unicode fashion) on BCB2007 if necessary.

Particular areas of concern are:

- Passing strings to/from Win32 API
  functions
- Interop with TXMLDocument
- 'Raw' strings used for RS232 comms, etc.

Rather than knife-and-fork the changes, I'm looking for guidelines that I can apply to ease the migration, while keeping backwards compatibility wherever possible.

If no such guidelines already exist, maybe we can formulate some here?

Answer (score 4):

The biggest issue is compatibility for C++Builder 2009 and previous versions, the Unicode differences are some, but the project configuration files have changed as well.  From the discussions I've been following on the [CodeGear forums](https://forums.codegear.com/category.jspa?categoryID=8), there are not a whole lot of choices in the matter.

I think the first place to start, if you have not done so, is the [C++Builder 2009 release notes](http://dn.codegear.com/article/38475).

The biggest thing seen has been the TCHAR mapping (to wchar or char); using the STL string varieties may be a help, since they shouldn't be very different between the two versions.  The mapping existed in C++Builder 2007 as well (with the tchar header).

Answer (score 2):

For any code that does not need to be explicitally Ansi or explitically Unicode, you should consider using the System::String, System::Char, and System::PChar typedefs as much as possible.  That will help ease a lot of migration, and they work in previous versions.

When passing a System::String to an API function, you have to take into account the new "TCHAR maps to" setting in the Project options.  If you try to pass AnsiString::c_str() when "TCHAR maps to" is set to "wchar_t", or UnicodeString::c_str() when "TCHAR maps to" is set to "char", you will have to perform appropriate typecasts.  If you have "TCHAR maps to" set to "wchar_t".  Technically, UnicodeString::t_str() does the same thing as TCHAR does in the API, however t_str() can be very dangerous if you misuse it (when "TCHAR maps to" is set to "char", t_str() transforms the UnicodeString's internal data to Ansi).

For "raw" strings, you can use the new RawByteString type (though I do not recommend it), or TBytes instead (which is an array of bytes - recommended).  You should not be using Ansi/Wide/UnicodeString for non-character data to begin with.  Most people used AnsiString as makeshift data buffers in past versions.  Do not do that anymore.  This is particularly important because AnsiString is now codepage-aware, and thus your data might get converted to other codepages when you least expect it.