# Any tips for speeding up C++ Builder code insight?

Tags: autocomplete, c++builder

Using C++ Builder 6, Ctrl-Space locks up the IDE for 3-5 seconds before presenting the suggestions list.

C++ Builder 2010 isn't much better.

Does anyone know any tips/tricks to speed up code insight?

Comment: C++Builder 6 is a decade old!  My recommendation would be to upgrade to a modern version.  (I can't even imagine having to use that version now, how do you get anything done?) I'm using 2010 and code insight works fine - not perfectly, but ok.

Comment: I know! Unfortunately the choice of IDE is out of my control.
There's an effort underway to port the codebase to C++ Builder 2010, but that's a non-trivial task (especially the AnsiString -> UnicodeString change)

Comment: I've done the porting thing as well.  The best suggestion is to dedicate your whole team to doing it in one go - it sounds to me like you're keeping two parallel branches going and that just doubles the work.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question about converting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392409/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-upgrade-a-complex-application-from-cbuilder-2007-to-2).  In practice, we replaced AnsiString with String, string with wstring, char with wchar_t (this one needed careful manual examination to avoid messing up what were meant to be byte pointers or arrays) and prefixed strings with L - all this was automatable! I also wrote an ostream-compatible class to handle output, since wostream wasn't ideal.  It took a while and wasn't trivial but was definitely worthwhile.

Comment: Yes, we do have two parallel branches - we're supporting and updating our older version while porting to C++ Builder 2010. We went the AnsiString -> String approach and did a mass replace on all our C-style string functions to use [Floating Functions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Floating_Functions). Seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuning your precompiled headers is probably the best bang for your buck. Code insight uses the compiler. This will also improve overall build times as well.

Comment: I agree with David and others: properly setting up a PCH file had always made the biggest difference in Code Insight speed for me. And one way to verify/validate your PCH setup is to look for external type files (*.#00, *.#01, *.#02, etc). If your project has many of these, it indicates non-optimal PCH setup (i.e. translation units are not sharing the PCH). And for Code Insight in headers, make sure your header files include what they use as in that scenario the IDE has no source context and will simply put that header in an empty source file.

Answer (score 1):

In 2010 and XE, using precompiled headers helps the issue quite a bit.

Comment: Even without PCH, I find Code Insight to be a lot faster in 2010 than it was in 6.